# Why can't I declare variables with let/const in Chrome's console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging some code and paused inside image error event. Now, in the console I type `const reader = new FileReader()` to try and look inside the blob URL, but the variable `reader` is still not defined. If I use `var` instead, it works correctly. Is it a bug in chrome, or there's a reason for this behavior?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce on `66.0.3359.181`. Does that still happen when you completely refresh the page and type in those commands (and those commands alone)?

Comment: It could have something to do with what Chrome does with command lines typed into the console. If, for example, the code is implicitly wrapped in a statement block, then the `let` would work but the variable would not be visible in subsequent command lines.

Comment: That said, it works for me too in 67.0.3396.79

Comment: Looks like you might be using a plugin / extension that's doing this  (or possibly a virus "shudder"),..  `util.js:31`,  that doesn't look like Chrome callee, and why it's wanting `Image.complete` for a console seems odd.

Comment: I think others are missing the step of stepping into code. When I place a debugger statement, I also cannot set a variable using let. This may have to do with Chrome Developer Tools and v8 optimizations detailed and this related SO question: stackoverflow.com/questions/28388530/ - I verified in 67.0.3396.79. Here's a fiddle, if you'd like to confirm: http://jsfiddle.net/49mx8twL/2/

Comment: @Jack  Oh, see.  Yeah.  Now things make sense..  Never even thought of setting a `const / let` inside a paused state JS before.

Comment: Agreed Keith (I threw the Upvote arrow your way because I thought you hit it on the nail as I've had similar issues in the past with extensions!) Right after, I started thinking of those weird quirks I've encountered when debugging code, and specifically accessing variables outside of the local scope. I'm thinking this is probably related since it seems `var` does work, but it's set to the `global` scope of the scope context. Step outside the code and the `var` declaration is no longer available. It's why we gotta explicitly set `window.myvar` to access after.

Comment: I should mention that let/const always works if I use the console normally, the issue only happens in a paused state. You can always reproduce it - pause the script in any way, type `const x = 1`, then `x` and you get undefined error. It probably gets confused with local scopes or something.

Comment: **Update**: someone from Google's DevTools team has raised a ticket in Chromium's bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1319338&q=debugger%20defined&can=2